# determine the cell holding the longest string with excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find which, cells hold the longest string in an excel spreadsheet.

I'm using the formula below to determine the length of the longest string

```
MAX(LEN(A2:A2000))
```

But here I'm stuck because I have no idea where to find this cell.

I don't want to go into a macro routine because it is a one-off job. However, if there is nothing else to do, well ... I'm ok to follow that route.

I'm all ears to your ideas.

Best.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get *address* of first longest string use:

```
 =CELL("address",INDEX(A2:A2000,MATCH(MAX(LEN(A2:A2000)),LEN(A2:A2000),0)))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

- `MAX(LEN(A2:A2000))` returns max len
- `MATCH(MAX(LEN(A2:A2000)),LEN(A2:A2000),0)` finds index of first cell with max len in range `A2:A2000`
- `INDEX(A2:A2000,MATCH(...)` returns *reference* to first string with max len
- `CELL("address",INDEX(..))` retrieves address from cell reference

[image]

**UPDATE:**

as follow up from comments, OP uses French excel version, so next formula working:

```
=CELLULE("adresse";INDEX(B1:B100;EQUIV(MAX(NBCAR(B1:B100));NBCAR(B1:B100);0)))
```

with array entry

Comment: Does Andy want to know the **value** of the longest string or **where** it is??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, as per my updated answer, he could also use `=CELL("address",INDEX(..))`

Comment: Hi , I want to know where it is.

Comment: @AndyK, see my updated answer: `=CELL("address",INDEX(A2:A2000,MATCH(MAX(LEN(A2:A2000)),LEN(A2:A2000),0)))` with array entry

Comment: Hi Simico , thanks for your answer. I tried it with my french version of excel , put the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER... It gives me an error 

`=CELLULE("address",INDEX(A1:A20000,EQUIV(MAX(NBCAR(A1:A20000)),NBCAR(A1:A20000),0)))`

Comment: try `=CELLULE("adresse",INDEX(B1:B100,EQUIV(MAX(NBCAR(B1:B100)),NBCAR(B1:B100),0)))`. You may also change `,` to `;` if your formula separator is semicolon (`;`)

Comment: I've changed it and it works. It was the semi-colon, which were creating issues. Thank you Simico. `=CELLULE("adresse";INDEX(B1:B100;EQUIV(MAX(NBCAR(B1:B100));NBCAR(B1:B100);0)))`

Comment: Would you mind amending your answer, please? I will give you a vote plus it will be useful for everyone else.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer with french version of formula:)

Comment: For me LEN() doesn't work with an array. It accepts text only. Is this new?